# Split a string into a tuple using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Given a string like `"name:Dave"` that I'd like to convert to a `Tuple<string,string>` is there a neat way to do this inline using LINQ, rather than first getting the array then parsing it?

I am parsing some config data from my `app.config` file like this:

```
<Data>
  <add key="John" value="instrument:guitar"/>
  <add key="Paul" value="instrument:bass"/>
  <add key="George" value="instrument:guitar"/>
  <add key="Ringo" value="instrument:drums"/>
</Data>
```

Which I want to convert to a `Dictionary<string,tuple<string,string>>` (I know this is an odd data structure!)

Starting with some code:

```
            var x = ((ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Data") as Hashtable))
                .Cast<System.Collections.DictionaryEntry>()
                .ToDictionary(n => n.Key.ToString(), n => something(n.Value.ToString().Split(':')));
```

I wondered if there's a neat LINQ way to do this in-line rather than write a utility function to get from String.Split's array into a single Tuple?

Comment: How about `.Select(n => new { n.Key, parts = n.Value.Split(':') })`?

Comment: won't `parts` be an array in this case?

Comment: Correct, I didn't say this was the final result.

Comment: That little detail basically _is_ the question... added a bit more detail

Comment: `.Select(n => new { n.Key, parts = n.Value.Split(':') }).Select(n => Tuple.Create(n.Key, n.Values[1]))`

Comment: That's a rather neat approach, to create an object then transform it... I was stuck wondering how to project the array into multiple fields of a single object

Comment: Another way would be to use Substring with IndexOf(":"), to create a new tuple in the first select. So something like .Select(n => new { n.Key, Tuple.Create(n.Value.Substring(0, n.Value.IndexOf(":")), n.Value.Substring(n.Value.IndexOf(":"), n.Value.Length) }); However, I think you're better off creating a nice static method in some helper class that makes it clear what's going on

Answer (score 4):

```
var source = new Dictionary<string, string>(){ { "John", "instrument:guitar" } };
var tuple = source.Select(x => new { key = x.Key, values = x.Value.Split(':') }).Select(y => new Tuple<string, string>(y.key, y.values[1])).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your string is basically an `XML` so I would just parse this using `XmlDocument` from `System.Xml` namespace. Then you can just use `GetElementsByTagName` because all values you want to retrieve has the same tag ( `<add />` ) and then just use it to create a dictionary like such :

```
string @xml = @"<Data>
<add key=""John"" value=""instrument:guitar""/>
<add key=""Paul"" value=""instrument:bass""/>
<add key=""George"" value=""instrument:guitar""/>
<add key=""Ringo"" value=""instrument:drums""/>
</Data>";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(@xml);
var dict = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>>();
doc.GetElementsByTagName("add")
    .OfType<XmlElement>()
    .Select(element =>
    {
        string key = element.Attributes["key"].Value;
        string[] value = element.Attributes["value"].Value.Split(':');
        dict.Add(key, new Tuple<string, string>(value[0], value[1]));
        return dict.Last();
    });
return dict;
```

Which can be shortened into something like this :

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(@xml);
Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>> dict = doc.GetElementsByTagName("add")
    .OfType<XmlElement>()
    .Select(element => new Tuple<string, string[]>(element.Attributes["key"].Value, element.Attributes["value"].Value.Split(':')))
    .ToDictionary(element => element.Item1, element => new Tuple<string, string>(element.Item2[0], element.Item2[1]));

return dict;
```

Or even shorter :

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(@xml);
Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>> dict = doc.GetElementsByTagName("add")
    .OfType<XmlElement>()
    .ToDictionary(element => element.Attributes["key"].Value, element => new Tuple<string, string>(element.Attributes["value"].Value.Split(':')[0], element.Attributes["value"].Value.Split(':')[1]));
return dict;
```

**EDIT :** *( After question edit )*

You can use `System.Configuration` library which contains `ConfigurationManager` object and do it like such :

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys.ToDictionary(
    key =>
        key,
    key =>
        new Tuple<string, string>(
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key].Split(':')[0],
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key].Split(':')[1]
        )
);
```

But you have to make sure that `app.config` contains only the keys you want to process using this method. If you try to process line which looks like `<add key="Willy" value="noinstrument" />` that method will break.

Comment: Yeah that's an interesting approach - I'm automatically assuming using the app.config related classes is easiest. Is there any problem accessing app.config as a regular XML file or is that quite normal and recommended?

Comment: @Mr.Boy When I wrote this answer there was no mention about `app.config` but still this can apply to use with this file since it is an ordinary `XML` file.

Comment: Apologies... it was implied by use of the Configuration classes but I should've stated directly  -hence the edit :)